# Drag & Drop using Dropzone and Seaside

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, seaside

I'm struggling a little with the dropzone implementation for dragging/dropping files. I am developing on a Smalltalk platform with Seaside on the front end. Currently, I am able to upload a file but unable to see the success icon as well as the progress bar appear at the time of upload. When I inspect elements on the web, I do see that the divs representing the success/progress are present. I do see the file size and file name appear just as the file gets dropped in. Can someone point out what I'm missing? My code is as follows:

```
| serverURL url | 

serverURL := RepWebSettings portalSettingsWebServerURL ifNil: [self session requestContext request uri serverURL].
url := serverURL , 
        html context actionUrl printString ,
         '&' , (html callbacks store: (Seaside.WAValueCallback on: [self uploadFileDroppedFiles])).

html div class: 'layoutBorder'; with: [
    html div id: 'draganddropupload'; class: 'dropzone'; 
        with: [
            html div class: 'dz-message'; with: [
                html image url: RepWebFileLibrary / #draganddropPng]]].

html script: ('
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        Dropzone.uploadMultiple = true;
        Dropzone.createImageThumbnails = false; 
        $("#draganddropupload").dropzone({
            url: "%1",
            success: function (file, response) {
                document.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });' bindWith: url).
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your example with Chrome's Developer Tools opened to the 'Console' tab what javascript errors do you see?  Seems like Dropzone manages the progress bar and checkmark.

From looking at their simple example:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/gh-pages/examples/simple.html

The only difference between what you've got and what they've got is that they're using a 'form' tag with the 'dropzone' class and you're using a 'div' tag.

So, it may be that Dropzone expects to operate in a 'form' and without any other inputs in that form.  So if it were me I'd change that div tag in your seaside code to a form, and make sure the new form wasn't nested inside another form on the page.